# Magento 1.9 change server and domain

Tags: magento-1.9, database

i wanted to clone a site running magento 1.9.3, I did below steps

- change DB credentials inside "local.xml"
- change URL inside DB table "core_config_data"

But when i try to access the site its broken even admin interface is, Below the screenshots. Hope anyone can help me out on this

[image] 
[image]

Comment: in question you mentioned magento 1 and  added tag for magento 2 as well. Which version you are using ?

Comment: @pawan its magento 1.9.3,

Comment: have you copied whole folder/files from server ? please remove `var` folder.

Comment: yeah i have copied all the files from the server and now i tried renaming the `Var` folder still the same

Comment: any error in console Or log file ?

Comment: yes i believe something is wrong https://snag.gy/pWL1t2.jpg

Comment: it seems js/css not loading. on Server are you using CDN ?

Comment: no this server don't use any CDN, but the path i have highlighted on the screenshot i believe there should be a `/` after the domain

Comment: Yes, I think in admin you forgot / at the end of base url and base secure url

Comment: glad to know, its working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just inspect your domain and found css path is

> http://buymalaysia.qatarshopping.qaskin/frontend/puro/puro01/css/customscrollbar.css

That means you forgot trailing slash at the end.

right CSS path should be

> http://buymalaysia.qatarshopping.qa/skin/frontend/puro/puro01/css/customscrollbar.css

in `core_config_data` base URL should be `http://buymalaysia.qatarshopping.qa/`